# Can't download any file with AsyncTask on mobile network

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I have an AsyncTask method for downloading a JSON file.  After downloading, on postExecute I populate my listview.

My problem is this method will not work when I'm connected to mobile network. I've tried it with different phones, or it will be stuck in ProgressDialog spinner, or it will show nothing after dismissing ProgressDialog on postExecute.

But when the phone is connected to the wifi network it's fine and I'll get my result.

**Method**

```
public class JsonDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
    private FileOutputStream out = null;
    private File filename = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,getClass().getName());
        mWakeLock.acquire();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Preparing List...");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while list is populating...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(100);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);
        ProgressBar progressbar=(ProgressBar)mProgressDialog.findViewById(R.id.pbar);
        progressbar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF4081"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... image_urls) {
        InputStream input = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(image_urls[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
            }
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            Log.i("in save()", "after mkdir");
            filename = new File(path+offlineJsonFileName +".txt");
            Log.i("in save()", "after file");
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            Log.i("in save()", "after outputstream");
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Log.i("in save()", "after outputstream closed");
            out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    input.close();
                    return null;
                }
                total += count;
                if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.toString();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null)
                    out.close();
                if (input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
            if (connection != null)
                connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        mWakeLock.release();
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            ReadFile();
    }
}
```

And I execute it like this:

```
jsonDownloader = new JsonDownloader();
jsonDownloader.execute(url);
```

Comment: any logcat error or warning?

Comment: No, nothing....

Comment: You have not even e.printStackTrace() in the catch blocks! You shou!d catch some more exceptions.

Comment: Remove the wakelock code. Also you have so much progress dialog code. Try with less. No color.

Answer (score 0):

```
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Log.i("in save()", "after outputstream closed");
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
```

Remove that all. Why close and reopen an output stream?

After you are done with the writing do a flush().

Comment: Thank's for the reply, I've tried all you said, but the problem still remaining

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by the following

```
class JsonDownloaderNew extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        System.out.println("Starting download");
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Preparing List...");
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while list is populating...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(100);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);
        ProgressBar progressbar=(ProgressBar)mProgressDialog.findViewById(R.id.pbar);
        progressbar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF4081"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            System.out.println("Downloading");
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);

            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            // Output stream to write file
            File filename = new File(path+offlineJsonFileName +".txt");
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            // flushing output
            output.flush();
            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        System.out.println("Downloaded");
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        ReadFile();
    }
}
```